# I'm trying to figure out which is correct; how old he was or how old was he?

Tags: word-order

What is the proper way to write, "I asked how old he was" or "I asked how old was he."

Comment: Both constructions are possible, but the uninverted one is the 'norm'. The inverted construction is, I believe, fairly common in the USA, but is probably best regarded as non-standard speech.

Comment: Or you could punctuate it:  *I asked, “How old was he?”*

Comment: We have an almost identical question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233769/what-will-be-the-word-order-in-converting-this-to-reported-speech)

Comment: "I asked how old he was." is **reported speech**, and nowadays, journalists makes tons of mistakes on live TV using it. I cannot understand why. They say things like "We asked the people fleeing what was their destination". instead of: We asked the fleeing people **what their destination was**. **People** forget to get rid of the question form. Some people anyway.

Comment: NB, @Jim, the proposed edit changes the meaning slightly. "Yesterday I asked how old he was" suggests "Yesterday I asked, 'How old is he?'" In the OP's form the past tense of "was" could be the result of the past tense of "asked." To ask "How old was he," you're referencing a point in the past, e.g. "How old was Shakespeare when he died?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I'm not sure what the right way is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is)

Comment: ***How old was he*** is a ***question*** (something you ***ask***, that expects a ***reply***). But ***how old he was*** is simply a ***noun phrase*** (compare *Write down **how old he was**, Write down **your name**, Write down **what he said,*** etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The standard construction is "I asked how old he was." The inverted construction would certainly be understood, as it's common in poetic license or the dialogue of certain fantasy characters. However, it's easy to see if we simplify the sentence. "I saw he was old" vs "I saw old was he." If we simplify still further, there is another sentence nested in this one: "He was old" (vs. "old was he"). "He" is the subject and "old" is its complement, and standard English syntax is for the complement to follow the verb (unlike standard Yoda syntax).

Comment: I think you're over-analysing. The inverted construction represents a blurring of the distinction between subordinate and main clauses. "How old was he" involves indirect reported speech, and is best treated as a subordinate clause, recognising that in this variety inversion does nor always distinguish main from subordinate interrogatives.

Comment: @BillJ See Jim's comment and mine on the OP; my initial assumption (and the simplest interpretation of the OP as written) is that the sentence doesn't necessarily contain a direct quote, but could be validly rewritten "I asked his age."

Comment: Complement, as you mentioned in your answer, has nothing to do with it. The point is that it's a valid, though non-standard construction, quite widespread in the USA. It's characteristic of non-standard speech and limited to a subset of the question-oriented contexts -- to contexts of a strong question orientation.

Comment: @BillJ Note that the OP asked "What is the proper way." While I find the above example "We asked the people... what was their destination" plausible (if bizarre), I have a hard time hearing "I asked how old was he" as anything but Yoda, and I'm in the USA. I'm not sure I can agree that it's a valid construction, but I'm open to a source documenting otherwise.